# What happened to java.util.stream.Streamable?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Early `jdk8-ea` javadocs [like this](http://download.java.net/lambda/b62/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) indicate there was a `java.util.stream.Streamable` interface, which would appear to have the same relationship to a `Stream` as `Iterable` has to an `Iterator`.

Now it seems like we're stuck with `Supplier<Stream>`, which is certainly not the same.

What happened to `Streamable` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's been removed some time ago. [The rationale](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2012-December/000703.html) for the removal was given by Brian Goetz:

> Currently the only 
>   implementor is Collection, and all of the other stream-bearing methods 
>   are serving up specialized streams (chars(), codePoints(), lines(), etc) 
>   with a method name that is more suitable than "stream".  So I think we 
>   should drop Streamable and leave the stream() / parallel() methods on 
>   Collection (or possibly move them up Iterable).

[And also](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2012-December/000680.html):

> I'm starting to think that Streamable is not carrying its weight.  I'd 
>   like to consider dropping Streamable, at which point the base-most 
>   implementation of parallel() is in Collection, and I'd also suggest we 
>   consider renaming that to parallelStream().

In [this other post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-February/001287.html) he adds:

> if everything that is Iterable is effectively 
>   Streamable (because Iterable has a stream()) method, and everything 
>   Streamable is effectively Iterable (because you can turn a Spliterator 
>   into an Iterator), aren't they then the same abstraction?

Comment: Sadly, `Iterable` has no more `stream` method :|