# Why isn't there an Interface for something that provides a Stream<E>?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In order to keep implementation details from leaking, instead of returning, e.g., a `Collection<MyCoolObject>`, one might implement `Iterable<MyCoolObject>`, which would then require implementing `Iterator<T>` from the `Iterable` Interface. Thus however the internal data structure is managed, the access to the elements is via the `Iterator`.

With Java 8, one might wish to add `Stream<MyCoolObject> stream()` to `MyCoolObject`. (See also: recommendation to support `stream` in the book *Java 8 Lambdas*). While adding the method isn't difficult (and I did read the Question about [Why Iterable Doesn't Provide Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114015/why-does-iterablet-not-provide-stream-and-parallelstream-methods)), it seems odd that Java did not add an Interface for `Streamable<T>` to mirror the `Iterable<T>` idea. (Well, a different name perhaps since `Streamable` exists for the ever use CORBA stuff).

I think I followed the Answer about why adding `Stream` to `Iterable` was potentially problematic, but I do not see why a `Streaming<T>` interface couldn't have been provided. For example, `Collections` could have implemented the `Streaming<T>` interface, and it would make it clearer for other objects that one could expect a `stream()` method.

Based upon an Answer to the above referenced Question, it is possible to get a `Stream` from the `Iterable` via

```
Stream s = StreamSupport.stream(iter.spliterator(), false);
```

but that seems like a lot of work given that `MyObject` could would like to just implement `stream()` to allow a user of the object to do

```
myObject.stream().filter(...).collect(...)
```

without the intervening conversion from the iterator.

Is there a reason for the lack of an interface for streaming capable objects? Is there a better approach than just implementing `stream()` on MyCoolObject and letting someone look through the Javadoc so they know it has a `stream()` method?

Or, is quite likely, am I misunderstanding something about the approach for Stream?

(Also, I implement `stream()` in CoolObject, but then forget to implement `parallelStream()`, which is something that would be alleviated by having the interface).

Comment: How does implementing an interface make it any clearer than just providing the method?  You have to look at the Javadoc either way.  (And why bother with `parallelStream()` when `stream().parallel()` does the same thing?)  You haven't made it particularly clear what you expect the _interface_ to add versus just adding a `stream()` method directly.

Comment: You don't need a `Streaming` interface to provide a `stream` method. `Iterable` is there to support for-each loops. Is there anything like that for streams, where an API needs to take a generic stream-producing object instead of just taking a stream?

Comment: @LouisWasserman for abstraction when you return an object? So that you can say: "here take this object, from which you can obtain a Stream, but you don't need to know exactly what type of object it is"

Comment: @LouisWasserman, fair enough about the Javadoc. But if `Iterable` exists "to be the target of a `for-each loop`" (from its Javadoc), then why not an interface to be the target of a `stream`? I am guessing consistency as to the reason. I create MyObject, and implement `Iterable`, but not `Streaming`? Just seems like it is missing something.

Comment: (Note that before Java 1.5 introduced for-each loops, `Iterable` didn't exist. Similarly, there was no `Enumerable` for the old pre-Java Collections Framework `elements`/`Enumeration` API.)

Comment: @user2357112, here might be a use case issue on my part. But I am creating an `interface` for essentially a Strategy pattern. Rather than specifying a method return `Collection<Result>`, I thought hey, don't force the Strategy Implementor to make such a specific return, instead just allow supporting iteration and streaming (as that is what is really needed). I can have my interface extend `Iterable<Result>` but then I must directly specify `Stream<Result> stream` on the interface? Just seems strange, but your comment about when Iterable was introduced was enlightening. Thank you.

Comment: @KevinO Why have you made the assumption that a collection is more specific than a stream? It's the other way around. If you return a stream you'd be returning something that is simultaneously more specific *and* less useful.

Comment: @KevinO A strategy that supplies some value is often better described by a functional interface, e.g. a Supplier<T>. A stream provides an `iterator()` method to get an iterator
 (only one time), so why not declare the strategy as Supplier<Stream<Result>>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happened to java.util.stream.Streamable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985854/what-happened-to-java-util-stream-streamable)

Comment: I wouldn’t object a name, just because there is a class of the same simple name in CORBA. There are so many classes in there, it would be hard to find a name which isn’t there. Just start with `Object`…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should probably augment any future answers.

I don't know why you think that returning an `Iterable<MyCoolObject>` rather than a `Collection<MyCoolObject>` is better. It might hide details indeed, and will create more problems as-well.

A Collection has a `known size` that plays a big role while splitting for parallel processing. This is reported as `Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.SUBSIZED`. So a `Collection.stream` will handle parallel streams much better then a `Iterable`, that will use:

```
public static <T> Spliterator<T> spliteratorUnknownSize
```

that is documented as:

> ... and implements trySplit to permit **limited parallelism**.

Which is obvious, since you don't know the size at all. *Under the current* implementation the batch size is `1024`. So, for example, for anything under 1024 elements you would not get any parallelisation at all.

Now as far as your question goes, *there used to be such a thing* in the early builds of jdk-8. It was called `java.util.stream.Streamable`. From what I know it was removed because there are methods that return a `Stream`, but not via the `stream()` method.

```
String::codePoints()
File::lines
Pattern::splitAsStream
... many others
```

So the only place where this would be implemented would be the Collections. And that as far as I can tell this would be a really isolated place.

**Aha moment**

Here is the [explanation](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2012-December/000703.html) from the people in charge of this.

As suggested here are the reasons for the removal:

> I am considering dropping the Streamable interface.  Currently the only 
>   implementor is Collection, and all of the other stream-bearing methods 
>   are serving up specialized streams (chars(), codePoints(), lines(), etc) 
>   with a method name that is more suitable than "stream".  So I think we 
>   should drop Streamable and leave the stream() / parallel() methods on 
>   Collection (or possibly move them up Iterable).

Comment: "It might hide details indeed..." Except it does this for the wrong reason. It makes assumptions about how it's going to be called. No function should ever be that arrogant. You want to return a type that is generic enough but also widely useful. Returning `Iterable` is not widely useful, hence why there are hardly any classes which *only* implement `Iterable` and do not implement `Collection`

Comment: I wish there was an interface for `isEmpty()` that things with that method have, but there isn't. Just like there's no `Streamable` interface. It's too late - that ship has sailed.

Comment: Thank you for the great response. The "Aha moment" was really interesting.

Comment: Good sleuthing to dig up Brian Goetz' comment. I'd suggest you pull in the key sentences from that email in addition to providing a link to the mail archive.

Answer (score 1):

[Because it was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985854/what-happened-to-java-util-stream-streamable), but you can easily roll out your own `Streamable` implementation if you need it:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Streamable<T> {
    Stream<T> stream();
}
```

If we take the example of the strategy pattern, you would then define it like so:

```
interface StreamStrategy<T> {
    Streamable<T> getStreamable();
}
```

Which can easily be implemented based on any backing object providing a method returning a `Stream<T>`, using a method reference. For example, if you have a collection:

```
class CollectionBasedStrategy<T> implements StreamStrategy<T> {
    @Override
    public Streamable<T> getStreamable() {
        return new ArrayList<T>()::stream;
    }
}
```

If `Collection` was extending such a `Streamable` interface, you would indeed not need to use the method reference. But otherwise there didn't seem to be much added value to put that in the JDK – and it can still be added later if needed.