# Streamable Interface : How empty() method returns Iterable?

Tags: java, java-8

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Streamable<T> extends Iterable<T>, Supplier<Stream<T>>
```

I was exploring the Streamable Interface and the first method that I came across was the `empty()` method that has the following definition.

```
static <T> Streamable<T> empty() {
        return Collections::emptyIterator;
    }
```

`Collections::emptyIterator` returns the `Iterator<T>` but the return type of this method is `Streamable<T>`. Streamble extends Iterable and Supplier and not Iterator interface.

I didn't understand how is that working fine.
Can someone please help me in understanding this?

I'm just failing in understanding the concept here. I wanted to know how is this working as I'm aware of how Inheritance works, but I'm unable to figure it out. I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: Wasn't this interface removed from jdk? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985854/what-happened-to-java-util-stream-streamable)

Comment: Which `Streamable` interface are you referring to? Can you post the full interface (or a reference to its javadoc)?

Comment: @Eran I'm talking about this: org.springframework.data.util.Streamable.

Comment: @RajWadhwa great, my answer applies to that interface. You should mention that in the body of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`empty()` returns a method reference `Collections::emptyIterator`.

In order for this code to pass compilation, that method reference must conform with the single abstract method of the `Streamable<>` interface.

`Collections`'s `emptyIterator()` takes no arguments and returns an `Iterator<T>`.

`Streamable<>` extends both `Iterable<T>` and `Supplier<Stream<T>>`, which means it has to implement two methods (`iterator()` and `get()`), but one of them cannot be abstract (otherwise it wouldn't be a functional interface).

`Collections`'s `emptyIterator()` can conform with `Iterable<T>`'s `Iterator<T> iterator()` signature.

So if `Streamable<T>` has a default implementation of `Supplier<Stream<T>>`'s `get()` method (if it doesn't, `Streamable<T>` cannot be a functional interface), `Collections::emptyIterator` can implement the `Streamable<T>` interface.

EDIT: If you were referring to [org.springframework.data.util.Streamable](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/util/Streamable.java), you can see that it does have a default implementation of `get()`:

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.util.function.Supplier#get()
 */
default Stream<T> get() {
    return stream();
}
```

Hence, any method reference that conforms with the single abstract method `Iterator<T> iterator()`, can implement that interface. Therefore `Collections::emptyIterator` can implement `Streamable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was definitely missing this point. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, this is the fully qualified name :  [`org.springframework.data.util.Streamable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/Streamable.html).

The thing is that in the current context :

```
static <T> Streamable<T> empty() {    
    return Collections.emptyIterator();
}
```

is not the same thing than :

```
static <T> Streamable<T> empty() {    
    return Collections::emptyIterator;
}
```

`return Collections.emptyIterator()` returns an `Iterator` object while the method expects a `Streamable`. That indeed cannot compile as you supposed.

But `return Collections::emptyIterator` doesn't return an `Iterator` object.    Instead, it defines the lambda body  associated to the `Streamable` functional interface object returned by `empty()`.

In fact this method reference :

```
return Collections::emptyIterator;
```

is equivalent to :

```
return () -> Collections.emptyIterator();
```

Why is it valid ?
Because `Streamable` is a functional interface defined as a function : `()-> Iterator<T>`
and `emptyIterator()` returns `Iterator<T>`.