# Is there a reason to not have a common `Streamable` interface?

Tags: java, java-stream

Both `Collection` and `Optional` have a `stream` method which we need to call if we want to `flatMap`. There could be an overload that would accept a `Streamable` and we would just flat map collections and optionals instead of first converting them to streams. So code like

```java
myStream.flatMap(obj -> obj.getCollection().stream())
```

or

```java
myStream.map(MyObject::getCollection).flatMap(Collection::stream)
```

would turn into

```java
myStream.flatMap(MyObject::getCollection)
```

Same with optionals.

Is there a downside?

Comment: Such an interface doesn’t seem to have any benefit other than eliminating nine characters in the code.  Or are there use cases I’m overlooking?

Comment: @VGR that's basically it, yes. I would also argue that method references are also a bit more readable as they represent a single method invocation and not a chain as is possible with lambdas

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it used to exist [What happened to java.util.stream.Streamable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985854/what-happened-to-java-util-stream-streamable)
and there was a reason for it to be removed at the time.
So I guess the answer to my question is that the same reason holds and addition of `Optional::stream` hasn't affected it